# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I want to set dynamic regex on *idnumber* by clicking on *idtype* dropdown returning a different regex value. It works fine until I select the last data on the which has "?" character on it and then the page become unresponsive and showing that error in the console tab.

Btw I am using inputmask plugin by:
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Herre's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let idTypes = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'id1',
      regex: '^([A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}(-)[0-9]{2}(-)[0-9]{6})$'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'id2',
      regex: '(CRN-)[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'id3',
      regex: '^(([0-9]{7}))$'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'id4',
      regex: '(PRN )([A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{11}|([0-9]{12}))( [A-Za-z])'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'id5',
      regex: '^([A-Za-z]){1}([0-9]{7})([A-Za-z])$'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'id7',
      regex: '^([A-Za-z]){2}([0-9]{7})$'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'id8',
      regex: '([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}[-][A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6})$'
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: 'id9',
      regex: '([0-9]{5})$'
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: 'id10',
      regex: '([0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{7}[-][0-9]{1})$'
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: 'id11',
      regex: '^([0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{13}?(-[0-9])?)$'
    },
  ]
  
  $(document).on('change', '#idtype', function() {
    let idNum = $('#idtype').val()
    let getRegex = idTypes.filter(el => {
      return el.id == idNum
    })
    let regex = getRegex[0].regex
    
    Inputmask.remove($('#idnumber'))
    Inputmask({
      regex,
      greedy: false
    }).mask($('#idnumber'))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/inputmask/bindings/inputmask.binding.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="idtype">ID TYPES</label>
  <select name="idtype" id="idtype">
    <option disabled="true" value selected>Select ID Type</option>
    <option value="1">id1</option>
    <option value="2">id2</option>
    <option value="3">id3</option>
    <option value="4">id4</option>
    <option value="5">id5</option>
    <option value="7">id7</option>
    <option value="8">id8</option>
    <option value="9">id9</option>
    <option value="10">id10</option>
    <option value="11">id11</option>
  </select>
  <label for="idnumber">ID NUMBER</label>
   <input
    type="text"
    name="idnumber"
    id="idnumber"
    autoComplete="off"
    placeholder
   />
</div>
```

As you can see in the data, the only data that has "?" with is the last data having id:11 which this is where the error shows once you select it.

please help! I'm running out of ideas on how to solve it.

here's the link to reproduce:
https://codepen.io/eyeswrong36/project/editor/DQQGYL

Answer (score 0):

There's a small mistake in the last regex: `{13}?` isn't supported. It seems to work well with just `{13}`.

Comment: I removed the "?" in {13}? and it works now.